# SharePoint 2013 Workflows List does not exist error

Tags: workflow, 2013, error, designer-workflow

I am creating a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow and I encountered an error which suspends my workflow. I've noticed that it only occures when I reference a lookup column to another list. The error details that I get from the browser are:

> RequestorId: bc0f2307-685a-cfc3-0000-000000000000. Details: RequestorId: bc0f2307-685a-cfc3-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 404 {"error":{"code":"-2130575322, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"List does not exist.\u000a\u000aThe page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."},"innererror":{"message":"List does not exist.\u000a\u000aThe page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.","type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","stacktrace":" at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)\u000d\u000a at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plRecycleBinCount)\u000d\u000a at

The setting is one server with SharePoint Server 2013 and Workflow Manager. I've installed and configured the Workflow manager as instructed in Microsoft's article- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx

I've enabled diagnostic logging in CA and in the USL log I get this:

> 07/26/2013 17:39:35.04 noderunner (0x2B48) 0x4EE8 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPConfigurationDatabaseSequence ajy5i DEBUG Returning SchemaVersion [15.0.10.0] for Database , Status = Online. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

The Workflow Management Logs does not report any errors. Which is very strange for me.

After two days of scouring the web I did not find anyone with similar problem. Any solutions, workarounds or pointers would be greatly appreciated. :)

Niki

Comment: Hi!
Today I faced exactly the same issue... Have you already found a solution ?

Comment: I think I can answer the question about how Niki is trying to access the lookup column ... because I get exactly the same. Create two custom lists in the same site. One list contains just item names and prices. The second list has a lookup column which looks up on those item names, and then the workflow looks up a price by using the id stored in the lookup column. It works for me on one farm, and returns this same error on the other. Both farms are one sp server, one sql server, one wf/sb server -- and I can subscribe either sp server to either wf/sb server, with no change to the above symptom

Answer (score 1):

I've came back to this problem after a while.

No, I can not access any information on the other list.

My setup is simple for test purposes. I have List1 and List2. List2 has only Title column (straight out of the box). List1 has Title, Lookup column and UserAndGroup column. All I do in the WF is try to log a message to Workflow history list containing the values of the 3 columns. The Title and UserAndGroup succeed but when it try to get the Lookup from List2 first it pauses with message

> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP NotFound to http:////_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')/Items(1)?%24select=ID%2CReferenceId%2CReference%2FTitle&%24expand=Reference Correlation Id: 8ccd2e3b-be78-3dfa-b246-3cfbec782473 Instance Id: af73d841-e862-472e-9c4f-ed8fd61ee8a1

Here I noticed that the list GUID is null and I'm not sure what this means. But I believe thuis to be the source of the problem. When I try it in the browser I recieve the same exception:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-2130575322, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.</m:message>
    <m:innererror>
        <m:message>List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.</m:message>
        <m:type>Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:type>
        <m:stacktrace>at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32&amp; plRecycleBinCount) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.EnsureListsData(Guid webId, String strListName) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.ItemByInternalName(String strInternalName, Boolean bThrowException) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.GetList(Guid uniqueId, Boolean fetchMetadata) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.GetById(Guid uniqueId) at Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPListCollectionServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, ClientValueCollection xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean&amp; isVoid) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, ClientValueCollection args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean&amp; isVoid) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.InvokeMethod(Boolean mainRequestPath, Object value, ServerStub serverProxy, EdmParserNode node, Boolean resourceEndpoint, MethodInformation methodInfo, Boolean isExtensionMethod, Boolean isIndexerMethod) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPathMember(Boolean mainRequestPath, String path, Object value, EdmParserNode node, Boolean resourceEndpoint, MethodInformation&amp; methodInfo) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPath(Boolean mainRequestPath, String path, String pathForErrorMessage) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestService.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)</m:stacktrace>
        <m:internalexception>
            <m:message>List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.<nativehr>0x81020026</nativehr>
                <nativestack/>
            </m:message>
            <m:type>System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException</m:type>
            <m:stacktrace>at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32&amp; plRecycleBinCount) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32&amp; plRecycleBinCount)</m:stacktrace>
        </m:internalexception>
    </m:innererror>
</m:error>
```

When I replace the GUID with the correct one the request seems to work. Can anyone tell me how I can fix this and what's cousing it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you trying to access the lookup column on the other list? Can you access any of the other columns on that other list? Where is that lookup column pointing to?

As for the noderunner, you can ignore that from this issue. That is not at all related to workflow... it's a search component.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-creating everything from scratch (i.e. don't use list templates)?  How about adding `servername` and `127.0.0.1` in your hosts file?

Answer (score 0):

Use a SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow and put your lookup value into a text field before running the 2013 workflow.  This works.

Alternatively, do the lookup from the list and filter based upon the selected value in the Current Item.

Make sure you don't have any workflows that are Suspended or Terminated but still running.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and worked around it by starting a 2010 workflow from within my 2013 workflow. The 2010 workflow does the lookups and sets parameters with the looked-up values (usually the ID number from the parent list).

These parameters are then available to the 2013 workflow.

Answer (score -2):

Try `SPWeb.Lists[listName]` instead of `SPWeb.Lists.tryGetList(listName)` and this exception will go away.

Comment: You are way off base here.  This is a SP Designer error, not an error with server-side code.  And even if it was, `.TryGetList()` would not return an error for a nonexistent list, but would return false.  That's the purpose of the function-not to break your code if the list does not exist.